# How To Write Rspec for Class methods in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, ruby-1.9.3

In my Rails application, I have a Model named `CrTransaction`. It contains the below class method,

```
def self.set_exclusion_attributes(ach_payment_id) 
  CrTransaction.where(:id => ach_payment_id).update_all(:updated_at => Time.now, :cr_status => 'EXCLUDED' , :is_cr_excluded => 1)
end
```

I have the below `rspec` test case for the above method to test the values of the fields `cr_status` and `is_cr_excluded` are updated or not. I don't know if this is perfect or not. Please help me to rectify the issues with this method if any.

```
@cr_transaction_obj10 = FactoryGirl.create(:ach_5, cr_status: nil, is_cr_excluded: false)
it 'method--set_exclusion_attributes--' do
  CrTransaction.set_exclusion_attributes(@cr_transaction_obj10.id)
  expect(cr_transaction_obj10.cr_status).to eq ('EXCLUDED')
  expect(cr_transaction_obj10.is_cr_excluded).to eq true
end
```